Is it adverbial or appositive?
Some will continue to ask the question "whether the war was worth the price."
(whether the war was worth the price)
The book answered it as an appositive, but the author did not explain how the idea is.
Let me take some discussion
Whether the war was worth the price, some will continue to ask the question.
Here in the above new sentence it seems to me,  an adverb of reason or condition modifies the whole next clause.
It can be illustrated as an appositive in only one way:
If it replaces the word " question"  i.e. some will continue [ whether the question about war was worth the price or not]
the question = Whether the war was worth the price.
Whether the war was worth the price = the question
Am I right or not?

apposition is a matter of whose definition you're using. In the strictest syntactic definition, the two constituents must refer to the same thing, must also stand in the same syntactic relation in clause structure, and  must function as subject.  Slightly less strict syntactic definitions remove the requirement that they function as subject. Laxer stylistic definitions remove the requirement that the constituents stand in the same syntactic relationship in clause structure and/or the requirement that they be co-referential.

In this case the answer would probably come down to how one understands the word whether.

Perhaps your author analyzed "whether ... worth the price" as an interrogative content clause and felt that it stood in apposition to "the question".


Some will continue to ask the question "whether the war was worth the price."

Whether the war was worth the price is the complement of the noun question.  It completes the meaning of the latter.
